# HTML = link inside won't show up as most updated version

Tags: html

I have a home page (home.html), which holds a link to a separate page (pagetwo.html).  A new version of pagetwo.html is copied/replace in the directory everyday.

When I open home.html, and click pagetwo.html I always get yesterdays report.  If I refresh the page, then I get today's report.

I cannot edit the code inside pagetwo.html because this page is created, copy/replace everyday.  The only thing that is static is home.html which has

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<script>
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
</script>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(10000);"><!--refreshs pages every 10 seconds-->
```

Is there anything I can put inside my " < a href="pagetwo.html" > "Page Two to make sure it is refreshed right away so it shows the correct pagetwo.html on the first try.

Thank you

Comment: Is it the same way no matter how you go to `~/pagetwo.html`? I mean do you get yesterday's result the first time if you go to `~/pagetwo.html` directly? Your browser might be caching an older copy. Is this a problem across all browsers?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @kush.  Great question- if I enter the URL directly, it shows me yesterdays result's.  Then if I refresh the page, it shows me today's.

Comment: Try generating a random query string on the link using JavaScript or a server side language. E.x. `<a href="pagetwo.html?4986432">` to try and bust the cache.